# extra character appears when using template strings in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, svg

i have this simple function that should return a string with svg `text` and multiple `tspan`s inside

```
export const TextBlock: (block: ValidatedTextBlock) => Promise<string> = async (block) => {
    const anchor =
        block.textAlign === 'center' ? 'middle' : block.textAlign === 'left' ? 'start' : 'end';
    const x =
        block.textAlign === 'center'
            ? block.width / 2 + block.left
            : block.textAlign === 'left'
            ? block.left
            : block.width + block.left;
    console.log(block.textLines);
    return `
    <text
      x="${x}"
      y="${block.top}"
      font-family="${block.fontFamily.split('/').pop()?.split('.').shift()}"
      font-size="${block.fontSize}"
      fill="${block.fill}"
      dominant-baseline="start"
      alignment-baseline="hanging"
      text-anchor="${anchor}"
      transform="$rotate(${block.rotation} ${block.left + block.width / 2} ${
        block.top + block.height / 2
    })"
    >
      ${block.textLines.map((line, i) => {
                console.log(line);
                return `
          <tspan
            dy="${i === 0 ? '0' : `${block.lineHeight}em`}"
            x="${x}"
            text-anchor="${anchor}"
            letter-spacing="${block.charSpacing}em"
            alignment-baseline="hanging"
          >
            ${line}
          </tspan>
          `;
            })}
    </text>
    `;
};
```

when I console log the `textLines` I get an array of strings as expected, but in the final svg i get this

```
<tspan
            dy="0"
            x="808"
            text-anchor="middle"
            letter-spacing="0em"
            alignment-baseline="hanging"
          >
            first line
          </tspan>
          ,
          <tspan
            dy="1.6em"
            x="808"
            text-anchor="middle"
            letter-spacing="0em"
            alignment-baseline="hanging"
          >
            second line
          </tspan>
          ,
          <tspan
            dy="1.6em"
            x="808"
            text-anchor="middle"
            letter-spacing="0em"
            alignment-baseline="hanging"
          >
            third line
          </tspan>
```

There is an extra comma between the lines, it is only between the lines not before or after, and If I run the function with only one string it doesn't happen, I have no clue how to even start debugging this because it is nowhere in my code (that I could see) and it's not an extra character appended to each line only in between the lines, I tried removing the index in the map function but I got the same result

Comment: When I log the line in the map it also logs just the text without any additional characters

Answer (score 2):

The result of your .map() call is being joined with the default comma separator. You should be able to add your own .join() after the map, like `.join("")`.

Something like

```
  ${block.textLines.map((line, i) => {
            console.log(line);
            return `
      <tspan
        dy="${i === 0 ? '0' : `${block.lineHeight}em`}"
        x="${x}"
        text-anchor="${anchor}"
        letter-spacing="${block.charSpacing}em"
        alignment-baseline="hanging"
      >
        ${line}
      </tspan>
      `;
        }).join("")}
```